# Bootstrap selectpicker remove all options and add new options

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, select

I am using bootstrap selectpicker, https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/

When the page gets loaded it get all default options from the server, and when I change country selectpicker, it gets AJAX response of an array,

```
$(document)
    .off("change", ".country")
    .on("change", ".country", function() {
        var country = $(this)
            .find(".country")
            .find(":selected")
            .val();
            
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "/general/getstates/" + country,
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data.states);
            
            //Need to remove all existing select options and need to set data.states values. 

            $('#states').selectpicker('refresh');
        }
    });
});
```

How can I achieve the same? Just use append? But how to remove the existing options?

Comment: Try : `$('#states').html(data.states).selectpicker('refresh');`

Comment: @Swati, this did not work and ```data.states``` is JSON array, what I did it prepared a dropdown view in Laravel and then inserted complete view in selectpicker. That way it worked.